# Running a script as sudo while using a virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, sudo

I need to run a python script as sudo inside a `virtualenv`. However, running `sudo python` will run the global python interpreter and not the one from the `virtualenv`.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why do you need sudo?

Comment: the python script in general does not need sudo, but there is a library used that needs sudo to run some system commands.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the absolute path to the interpreter.  Which you can discover by running, as normal user:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

The "activation" of a virtualenv is nothing more sophisticated than a hack to `PATH`.